# DAX ALLEXCEPT ignores Filter Context?

Tags: dax, powerpivot

Need a Quarter-To-Date measure when a *fiscal* calendar is being used.  Thought the following would work:

```
QTD =
CALCULATE (
    [Total Amount],
    FILTER (
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Calendar', 'Calendar'[FiscalYear] ),
        'Calendar'[FiscalQuarter] = MIN ( 'Calendar'[FiscalQuarter] )
            && 'Calendar'[Date] <= MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
    )
)
```

However, even though the ALLEXCEPT function is saying NOT to "reset" the [FiscalYear] column, the measure is being calculated without regard to the fiscal year of the pivot coordinates.  So the formula only works for the first fiscal year.
Anybody have any idea why the formula doesn't work as I anticipated?
TIA

Answer (score 1):

Found a relevant thread on powerbi.com (link [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Filter-and-Allexcept/m-p/76492#M31868)), and I kinda sorta understand.
It seems that when you use the FILTER function with a date table it automatically applies an ALL() and you lose the filter context.
For my QTD formula the following works correctly:

```
CALCULATE(
 [Total Amount],
 FILTER(
   ALL( 'Calendar' ),  
   'Calendar'[FiscalYear] = MIN( 'Calendar'[FiscalYear] )
     && 'Calendar'[FiscalQuarter] = MIN( 'Calendar'[FiscalQuarter] )
     && 'Calendar'[Date] <= MAX( 'Calendar'[Date] )
 )
)
```

Please reply if you know of a simpler formula. The fiscal quarter ends, btw, do NOT align with the calendar quarter ends.